# gitlab-runner как сервер

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-runner

Подскажите, почему раннеры гитлаба обращаются к гитлабу как к серверу, а не наоборот. Кажется, что гитлаб — ключевое звено и именно он должен задачи раздавать.

Answer (score 1):

> почему раннеры гитлаба обращаются к гитлабу как к серверу, а не наоборот.

потому что они клиенты, а он сервер. банальная клиент-серверная модель: **инициатива при подключении** должна исходить именно от клиентов.

> он должен задачи раздавать

так и есть: задачи раздаёт именно сервер, выбирая подходящих клиентов из (динамически обновляемого) списка подключившихся к нему клиентов.

Answer (score 1):

1. Раннеры могут быть короткоживущими, и их старт не обязательно совпадает со стартом гитлаба. Из очевидных плюсов - они могут быть добавлены в гитлаб в любой момент.
2. Чтобы не открывать порты раннеру на вход, они могут быть в приватных окружениях, безопасность, все дела.
3. Раннер можно запустить везде. На машине девелопера. На продакшене, куда нельзя пускать извне итд итп